# Where one can find example sentences with translations?

Tags: translation

I know there is http://www.hsk.academy/ which gives translations up to HSK2. But maybe there are other resources? Ideal variant would be translated news, they are especially hard to read without help. But any other variants are good too.

Comment: jukuu is a good source.

Answer (score 1):

With a pop-up dictionary in your browser to help you pronounce characters, http://www.iciba.com/ can be quite useful (especially for more rare words that might not be in a modest sized traditional, as opposed to primarily web-based) dictionary. Most (Chinese) words will have many example sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to haksayng, iciba is a good choice. However as a dictionary, nowadays dict.cn and more websites are better.

I have to say one thing that is very useful when I learn English, and perhaps even more helpful when learning Chinese, is a function on iciba.com called 双语例句. You put the phrases you want to lookup in the iciba's search box, hit search and if you look at this 双语例句 section, you will find that they are accurately translated.

It's actually how it worked, at the beginning Kingsoft want to make a phrase based function that can translate not only words, from Chinese to English. So they collected a lot of professionally translated article, from English to Chinese and break them down. The problem is, this reverse look up usually ends up poorly because you usually say something in English in one way, but say it in Chinese in another way. So in this case, you don't find it super helpful to translate from Chinese to English. However, if you take the other side of this function, it works surprisingly well.